# Debugging apache seg fault with gdb

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

Apache on a production server of mine is seg faulting intermittently. I have enabled core dump option in apache configuration and have several dumped core files. Unfortunately, since it is a production server, apache or the loaded modules are not compiled with debug symbols. From what I understand, gdb cannot do much without debug symbols.

Can I at least find out which module is causing the seg fault, without debug symbols? If so, how?

Following is the output from a gdb backtrace

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0xb7f1f832 in _dl_sysinfo_int80 () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#1  0xb7be82bc in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#2  0xb771652a in ?? () from /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_pagespeed.so
No symbol table info available.
#3  0xb75df576 in ?? () from /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_pagespeed.so
No symbol table info available.
#4  0xb7715c20 in ?? () from /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_pagespeed.so
No symbol table info available.
#5  0xb7be4a49 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#6  0xb7b2a63e in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
```

Does this mean that /lib/ld-linux.so.2 is causing the seg fault?

Comment: Looks like mod_pagespeed.so contains something non-threadsafe. Best bet is to report this upstream, doesn't seem a question that suitable for this forum